# How to split list data and populate to a DataFrame?

Tags: python

I have a list of items and want to clean the data with certain conditions and the output is a dataframe.
Here's the list:

```
[
  "Onion per Pack|500 g|Rp18,100|Rp3,700 / 100 g|Add to cart",
  "Shallot per Pack|250 g|-|49%|Rp22,300|Rp11,300|Rp4,600 / 100 g|Add to cart",
  "Spring Onion per Pack|250 g|Rp7,000|Rp2,800 / 100 g|Add to cart",
  "Green Beans per Pack|250 g|Rp5,900|Rp2,400 / 100 g|Add to cart",
  ]
```

into

| name | unit | discount | price | unit price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Onion per Pack | 500 g |  | Rp18,100 | Rp3,700 / 100 g |
| Shallot per Pack | 250 g | 49% | Rp22,300 | Rp11,300 |
| Spring Onion per Pack | 250 g |  | Rp7,000 | Rp2,800 / 100 g |
| Green Beans per Pack | 250 g |  | Rp5,900 | Rp2,400 / 100 g |

Currently my code is:

```
datas = pd.DataFrame()
for i in item:
    long = len(i.split("|"))
    if long == 5:
        data = {"name": i.split("|")[0]
                "unit": i.split("|")[2]
                "discount": ""
                "price": i.split("|")[3]
                "unit price": i.split("|")[4]}
        dat = pd.DataFrame(data)
        datas.append(dat)
    else:
        data = {"name": i.split("|")[0]
                "unit": i.split("|")[2]
                "discount": i.split("|")[4]
                "price": i.split("|")[6]
                "unit price": i.split("|")[7]}
        dat = pd.DataFrame(data)
        datas.append(dat)
```

Is there a more efficient way? A shorter way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes (*much* more efficient). However, first you'll need to sort out your source data so that *each value has its own field*. If a field is blank, it must be left as such; *not* populated with the value from the next field.  For example: `"Onion per Pack|500 g||Rp18,100|Rp3,700 / 100 g|Add to cart"`. Note the 'double delimiter' after 500g, indicating the next field is empty.

Comment: For starters, call `i.split('|')` only once in the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd using a map; try:

```py
ids = {
    5: [0, 2, -1, 3, 4],
    8: [0, 2, 4, 6, 7]
}

datas = pd.DataFrame()

for i in item:
    i = i.split("|")
    long = len(i)
    data = {
        "name": i[ids[long][0]],
        "unit": i[ids[long][1]],
        "discount": i[ids[long][2]] if ids[long][2] != -1 else "",
        "price": i[ids[long][3]],
        "unit price": i[ids[long][4]],
    }

    datas.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Comment: Generally, iterating a DataFrame is a strong hint there is a more efficient / robust solution is available and should be avoided in the majority of cases.

Comment: This only leads me to the conclusion I need to learn pandas and numpy much better ^_^

Comment: I’d agree.  ;-)  That being said, OP *first* needs to sort out their source data, so the more efficient broadcasting methods can be used.

Comment: I updated the answer to only split once, after all it's a bit heavy hhh

Comment: @S3DEV, An upvote on the answer will be more than welcome ;)

Comment: I've popped an answer on, as you mentioned you'd like to learn pandas better.  I hope this helps to show and explain a different (efficient) approach for easily populating a DataFrame.  :-)

Comment: suggestion: Make a list of dict and create the DataFrame once at the end. For a greater number of rows, this is more efficient. Also, .append() is deprecated mainly for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Once the source data has been cleaned (preferably by the provider) and **each field is defined** - ensuring an equal number of fields through the dataset - the following very simple approach can be used to populate the DataFrame:

**Data:**

```
cols = ['name', 'unit', 'discount', 'price', 'unit_price', 'other']

# Fields are defined by placing a 'double delimiter' indicating empty fields.
items = ["Onion per Pack|500 g||Rp18,100|Rp3,700 / 100 g|Add to cart",
         "Shallot per Pack|250 g|49%|Rp22,300|Rp4,600 / 100 g|Add to cart",
         "Spring Onion per Pack|250 g||Rp7,000|Rp2,800 / 100 g|Add to cart",
         "Green Beans per Pack|250 g||Rp5,900|Rp2,400 / 100 g|Add to cart"]
```

**Population:**

The **cleaned source data** can be populated directly into the DataFrame via the `data` parameter. In the case below, a 'generator expression' is used to iterate the dataset efficiently and split on the field delimiter.

The next statement removed the additional column, which is not to be included in the output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=(i.split('|') for i in items), columns=cols)
df.drop('other', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**Output:**

```
                    name   unit discount     price       unit_price
0         Onion per Pack  500 g           Rp18,100  Rp3,700 / 100 g
1       Shallot per Pack  250 g      49%  Rp22,300  Rp4,600 / 100 g
2  Spring Onion per Pack  250 g            Rp7,000  Rp2,800 / 100 g
3   Green Beans per Pack  250 g            Rp5,900  Rp2,400 / 100 g
```

Comment: but notice that sometimes there're 5 cols and sometimes 8

Comment: Yes - I've cleaned the data, ensuring an equal number of fields throughout the dataset. This is a prerequisite for clean data engineering and analysis.  (Standard practice)

Comment: It changes the whole question....

Comment: The question states "I have a list of items and want to **clean the data** with certain conditions **and the output is a dataframe**."  The original code is flimsy and contains dirty data. Therefore (as with any data analysis classroom or professional) the data must be cleaned.  You're right, does not simply correct OP's code.  It offers a *new approach* (albeit, more efficient (as requested) and robust) and hopes to instruct OP on a best-practice method.

Comment: All good mate :)

Comment: You should note that cleaning data does not mean editing the input. You want a procedure - a function to call - that does it. The reason is maintainability and reproducibility.

Comment: @creanion - Professionally, I'd disagree.  *Often* times we receive dirty data that must go back to the provider to be revised. In this case, my editing the source data, is equivalent to sending the data back to the provider asking for the fields to be delimited properly. This provides greater maintainability, rather than hack upon hack to clean dirty data which should have been provided correctly from the source.  That aside - **the purpose of this answer is to demonstrate the efficient way to load a DataFrame.**

Comment: If you can change that part of the pipe, sure, that sounds good. But most data cleaning tasks deal with data as it is. I agree with the initial sentiments - even if you have that purpose with the answer, it misses the important parts of the question. Loading a DataFrame with regular data is easy.